# Failed to execute com.github.eirslett

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, intellij-idea

I've recently started on https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ tutorial and I'm stuck on "Loading JavaScript Modules Example 8". When I add:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

to pom.xml, it highlights it as red and says **Plugin 'com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:' not found**. I hope someone could help. Thank you.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Have you tried to run "Reload" from Maven tool window?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I've managed to continue without this plugin;

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to the pluging fixed the issue for me.

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v12.19.0</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.14.8</npmVersion>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>npm install</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>webpack build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>webpack</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to include the plugin's version in your pom, as per [this](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installation) section of their repo.

Looks like the latest version (per the repo's [tags](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/tags) and per [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)) as of right now is 1.10.3:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3</version>
        ...
    </plugin>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue while working on this tutorial. After reading some other workarounds, a quick solution for me was to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, add the version to the plugin, which in my case was:

```
            <version>1.10.3</version>
```

Then, reload all Maven projects, and the red lines go away.